# where does cy variable coming from in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am have installed ESlint in out test project and it started to show me few errors that i need to resolve

one of the error is in cy.request('someURL');

The error is cy is undefined

so I have added a import statement on top of file like this

```
import { cy } from 'cypress';
```

After adding this statement none of the requests are going through I am getting this error when i try executing the tests.

[image: Error]

Tests are executing perfects once i remove the import statement

where am i going wrong

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`cy` is a global variable. Much like `location`. So really it is `window.cy`. You can add it to the globals in Eslint. Don't import `cy` from cypress.

```
{
    "globals": {
        "cy": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/* global cy */
```

import above in your test file (cypress test file ex: cypress/integration/login.js