# ESLint: 'cy' is not defined (Cypress)

Tags: reactjs, eslint, cypress

I've just started using Cypress with my React Typescript project. I've gotten some simple tests to run:

```js
describe('settings page', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
  });
  it('starts in a waiting state, with no settings.', () => {
    cy.contains('Waiting for settings...')
  });
  it('shows settings once settings are received', () => {
    const state = cy.window().its('store').invoke('getState')
    console.log(state) // different question: how do I get this to be the state and not a $Chainer?
  });
});
```

It runs in Cypress just fine. But I get Typescript errors in Webstorm, saying that `cy` is not defined (a TS and ESlint error) and an error on `describe` saying `all files must be modules when the --isolatedModules flag is provided`.

I can make it a JS file instead of a TS file, then I still get `cy` is not defined.

I've tried `import cy from 'cypress'` but then I get `ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'` which is a whole other can of worms (I'm taking baby steps in writing my tests and haven't had to import anything yet...)

`/// <reference types="cypress" />` **does not work.**

#### Update (sort of)

I've followed instructions [here](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/use-typescript-with-cypress/) and have made a little progress. To my already very full React webpack.config.dev.js I added the recommended code:

```js
          { // TODO inserted for cypress https://stackoverflow.com/a/56693706/6826164
            rules: [
              {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
              }
            ]
          },
```

to the end of the list of rules (just before the file loader).

When I do this as well as setting up the `plugins/index` file as indicated in the article, the cypress "home screen" runs but when I click to open my tests, it takes very many seconds and then shows lots of errors, starting with

```
integration\settings.spec.ts
This occurred while Cypress was compiling and bundling your test code. This is usually caused by:

A missing file or dependency
A syntax error in the file or one of its dependencies
Fix the error in your code and re-run your tests.

./cypress/integration/settings.spec.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for C:\Users\...\...\front_end\cypress\integration\settings.spec.ts.
 @ multi ./cypress/integration/settings.spec.ts main[0]
```

Followed by, actually, a lot of Typescript output such as this:

```
C:\Users\jtuzman\dev\...\...\src\__tests__\Errors.test.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\jtuzman\dev\...\...\src\__tests__\Errors.test.tsx(37,41)
      TS2339: Property 'toBeTruthy' does not exist on type 'Assertion'.

C:\Users\jtuzman\dev\...\...\src\__tests__\Errors.test.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\jtuzman\dev\...\...\src\__tests__\Errors.test.tsx(41,45)
      TS2339: Property 'toBeDefined' does not exist on type 'Assertion'.
```

Notice that these are now errors for code outside the test files (although perhaps that makes sense). Many of them are for files in which I'm using Jest rather than Cypress, and many errors, as you can see, seem to be related to it inferring an `Assertion` type on `expect` that is not Jest, such that it thinks the `toEqual` matcher is wrong.

All the while, in Webstorm ESLint is still complaining about all my `cy` and TypeScript is underlining all those Jest assertions mentioned in the output.

This is all with a ts test file. If I rename the file to js, it says the file has no tests.

Any help? I love Cypress but I'm having a hell of a time getting it to work fully!

Comment: Did you get it solved? I am facing similar issue.

Comment: Hi, I want to ask about eslint, so I need to implement eslint into my cypress project and add eslint-plugin-cypress as well? right?

Answer (score 162):

I got that error after upgrading to cypress version 4+. I installed the `eslint-plugin-cypress` 
https://github.com/cypress-io/eslint-plugin-cypress
and activated it in the extends configuration either in package.json or in separate config file:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "plugin:cypress/recommended"
  ]
},
```

Comment: Still correct answer, but in 2022 i had to edit .eslintrc

Comment: Still works. `npm install -D eslint-plugin-cypress` and add it in .eslintrc.js

Answer (score 98):

### Add .eslintrc.json to cypress directory

In `.eslintrc.json`

```
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:cypress/recommended"
  ]
}
```

[image]

- I do not install `eslint-plugin-cypress`, and it fix the problem

Comment: You need to install the plugin. The reason it looks like the problem is fixed is because ESLint will error out and stop linting the directory so all the warnings disappear. It looks like you're using VSCode, so you can click the ESLint tab in the bottom right to verify this.

Comment: Still I get this error Module build failed (from ./node_modules/cypress-plugin-tab/src/index.js): ReferenceError: Cypress is not defined

Comment: Can you look at this [question](https://github.com/Shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/issues/49)

Comment: Doesn't work ERROR in [eslint] Failed to load plugin 'cypress' declared in '.eslintrc': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-cypress'

Answer (score 27):

## Specify `cy` in eslintrc globals

[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062642/where-does-cy-variable-coming-from-in-cypress)

> cy is a global variable. Much like location. So really it is window.cy. You can add it to the globals in Eslint. Don't import cy from cypress.

```
{
  "globals": {
    "cy": true
  }
}
```

Added that to my `.eslintrc` and fixed the issue

Comment: Many thanks. Works for me without plugin install and import cy.

Answer (score 14):

I struggled a lot then this helped...
by adding **this one line** in **either of two config files**, `eslintrc.json` or `eslintrc.js`
(if u have other dependencies in extends, append them as well after it)

```
extends: ['plugin:cypress/recommended'],
```

Comment: and don't forget run - yarn add eslint-plugin-cypress --dev

Comment: Why do you have two eslint config files?

Comment: @Spikatrix plz feels free to configure one only.

Comment: @CodeWorld Yes, but your answer says two config files. I was just wondering why that would be the case.

Comment: @Spikatrix Actually that's silly me. Since I found it after lot of struggle and it was working, so I followed the motto don't touch what is working. (But whatever you are suggesting is definitely more correct)

Comment: It could be in your `package.json` config for the same too like this:

  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "plugin:cypress/recommended"
    ]
  }

Answer (score 13):

The Cypress ESLint plugin will get rid of these warnings:

- `yarn add -D eslint-plugin-cypress` (https://github.com/cypress-io/eslint-plugin-cypress)
- add `.eslintrc` to the root of your project with the following:

```json
{
    "plugins": ["cypress"],
    "extends": ["plugin:cypress/recommended"],
    "rules": {
        "jest/expect-expect": "off"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

at the top of your file put

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
```

or download the [official types](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/develop/cli/types)

source: [official cypress intellisense docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/intelligent-code-completion.html#Set-up-in-your-Dev-Environment)

Comment: Thanks but that's actually not working at all. I also tried downloading @types/cypress and adding it to my tsconfig, and that doesn't help any of the problems.

Comment: Still I get this error Module build failed (from ./node_modules/cypress-plugin-tab/src/index.js):
ReferenceError: Cypress is not defined

Answer (score 8):

Try.. `import cy from "cypress"` this solved the problem for me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack-overflow . you can use this link for improve your answer  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 5):

Just add these lines to your `tsconfig.json` file for e2e tests:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["cypress"]
}
```

This adds support for cypress types.

Answer (score 5):

I replaced the old style of type referencing,

`/// <reference types="cypress" />`

with this silly import

`import type {} from 'cypress';`

And the IDE now both recognizes Cypress's globals while also avoiding the "isolatedModules" issue it has with tsconfig.json

Answer (score 3):

Seems I found a remedy that works (at least) for me. Adding this import to the top of the test:

```ts
import _Cypress from "cypress";
```

relaxes and comforts the ESLint plugin. Actually any name for the import can be used instead of "_Cypress": any that conforms your sense of beauty, does not conflict with anything and starts with underscore (to not provoke ESLint again). Of course, it looks like a kind of voodoo. I don't know why it works and probably there are better ways to present ESLint Cypress's globals, but I don't know them.

Comment: It probably brings `cypress.d.ts` into scope.

Answer (score 2):

```
/* global cy */
```

import above in your test file

example:
suppose you have login test ("cypress test file ex: cypress/integration/login.js")

Comment: Is this a complete answer?

Comment: @user17242583 try other above solutions also, all solutions are correct but it depends on various issues, in my case this solution worked.

Comment: how does this solution work? where did you get it from please ?

Answer (score 1):

For me adding `.eslintignore` in root directory and placing `*.cy.js` for all my test files was only workaround.

It seems that for the rest of us the working solution really is installing `eslint-plugin-cypress` and adding:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "plugin:cypress/recommended"
  ]
},
```

but idt didn't helped in my case because this plugin is no longer supported (almost for a year now) so it ended with critical error when combined with `cypress-axe`.

Answer (score 0):

add this to jest.config.js

```html
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '/cypress',
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `config` object with `defineConfig` in the `cypress.confi.ts` file
like so

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
      return config;
    },
  },

  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "create-react-app",
      bundler: "webpack",
    },
  },
});
```