# ReferenceError 'process not defined' when executing Cypress test

Tags: testing, cypress

Trying to execute any of the tests leads to this error popping up.

I am using Cypress 6.5.0

Really clueless about what to do.

**Sorry for the image, but it was much better to show it this way.**

[image]

And also the StackTrace.

```
at Object../node_modules/is-ci/node_modules/ci-info/index.js (webpack:///node_modules/is-ci/node_modules/ci-info/index.js:5:1)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
at Object../node_modules/is-ci/index.js (webpack:///node_modules/is-ci/index.js:3:18)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
at Object.eval (webpack:///node_modules/cypress/lib/util.js:21:14)
at Object../node_modules/cypress/lib/util.js (http://localhost:37869/__cypress/tests?p=test/e2e/support/index.js:87250:31)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
at Object.eval (webpack:///node_modules/cypress/index.js:9:14)
at Object../node_modules/cypress/index.js (http://localhost:37869/__cypress/tests?p=test/e2e/support/index.js:82972:31)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
From previous event:
at runScriptsFromUrls (http://localhost:37869/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:177985:98)
at Object.runScripts (http://localhost:37869/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:177999:11)
at $Cypress.onSpecWindow (http://localhost:37869/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:167733:19)
```

Comment: May happen when using Next since process.env doesn't get inlined from the build, this is some Next.js magic. I am still looking for a way to mock this "process" object, setting window.process in the before hook doesn't work because the build fails.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This happened for me when I imported cypress within my test, removing that fixed the issue

Comment: I confirm that importing cypress in the test file causes the error, for me, it was eslint complaining for undefined `describe`, `it` and `cy`, which I fixed by adding `import { cy, describe, it } from "cypress";`, but this line is causing the error.
Anyway, to supress eslint errors for cypress, follow these instructions https://stackoverflow.com/a/66268013/477932

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes by mistake, Visual Studio Code will auto-import unnecessary libraries. You should delete them. For me it was

`import { cli } from 'cypress';`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have something in `/support/index.js` (since it's mentioned in the stack trace) that should be in `/plugins/index.js` (since it has an invalid use of `process` which is only available in node.js).

Cypress runs both a browser process and a background node.js process.

`/support/index.js` is used to augment the browser process, and `/plugins/index.js` is used to augment the node.js process.

If you mix them up when adding a library, a task, or a file preprocessor you get an error of the type you show.

What's in `/support/index.js`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove import cypress from "cypress" from your POM fi

Answer (score 1):

If you just updated to `react-scripts 5.x` and facing this issue, there is currently a PR to fix it but a workaround to get your tests working ASAP is to update the `env.js`  file in the react scripts node module as referenced in this [PR](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/12121/files).

*NB: If you have a private artifact repository manager on jfrog it is advisable to push this fix to your registry and pull react scripts from there until the fix becomes publicly available.*

TLDR;
You just updated to react 5.x and your cypress tests show the error below;

[image: Cypress process is not defined error]

Solution
File: `node_modules/react-scripts/config/env.js`

Change the `stringified` method to:

```js
    // Stringify all values so we can feed into webpack DefinePlugin
    const stringified = {
    'process':{}, // This is the only line added to the previous method
    'process.env': Object.keys(raw).reduce((env, key) => {
      env[key] = JSON.stringify(raw[key]);
      return env;
    }, {}),
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

When we drive out gloval variable from JSON visual studiao automatically Import
import { cli } from 'cypress';

Comment: This is offering the [same advice as @canbax offered last year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67871562/3025856)—though the confusing wording makes it hard to be sure that's what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

I commented following line from support/command.js and that reso I am using cypress 8.7

const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue was coming because of this statement in **command.js** file.

*const cypress = require("cypress");*

I removed it and the script worked perfectly.