# Cucumber [ERROR] Could not resolve "node:perf_hooks"

Tags: cucumber, cypress

I recently upgraded **cypress** from **9** to **11** and when I start it using

`npx cypress open`

I do not get any issues running the tests.

When I start it using:

`npx cypress run`

It returns me the following error:

```
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "node:perf_hooks"

    node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/time.js:27:34:
      27 │ const node_perf_hooks_1 = require("node:perf_hooks");
         ╵                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  The package "node:perf_hooks" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.

Error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/time.js:27:34: ERROR: Could not resolve "node:perf_hooks"
    at failureErrorWithLog (/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1636:15)
    at /node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1048:25
    at runOnEndCallbacks (/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1471:45)
    at buildResponseToResult (/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1046:7)
    at /node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1075:16
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:697:9)
    at handleIncomingPacket (/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:752:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:673:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

I am afraid that I am missing some polyfill plugins, my current ones are:

```js
const createEsbuildPlugin = require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild');
const { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } = require('@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill');
const nodePolyfills = require('@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill').NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin;

...

  on(
    'file:preprocessor',
    createBundler({
      plugins: [NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(), nodePolyfills(), createEsbuildPlugin.default(config)],
    }),
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved removing the import of cypress.config.ts in one of my step definition files. I was doing something like:

```js
import base from '../../../../cypress.config'; // WRONG
```

which is absolutely wrong, this fixed for me all the errors like:

```
[ERROR] Could not resolve "fs"
[ERROR] Could not resolve "fs/promises"
[ERROR] Could not resolve "stream"
[ERROR] Could not resolve "stream/promises"
[ERROR] Could not resolve "console"
[ERROR] Could not resolve "crypto"
...
etc.
```

I get the hints reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66378164/referenceerror-process-not-defined-when-executing-cypress-test).