# Cypress and cy undefined in commands.js, but everything works

Tags: javascript, webstorm, cypress, eslint

When typing a custom command into `commands.js`, WebStorm's linter says that both `Cypress` and `cy` are undefined and does not provide any IntelliSense.
Both are perfectly defined in any `integration` files.

commands.js

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('command', () => {
  cy.get('div');
});

// ESLint: 'Cypress' is not defined.(no-undef)
// ESLint: 'cy' is not defined.(no-undef)
```

index.js

```js
import './commands.js'
```

This error does not appear in VSCode. Instead both `Cypress` and `cy` are defined as `any`.

Regardless of this error, however, the tests work fine.

What can I do to have the linter recognize Cypress in its own files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found some solutions.

### Add reference

Put this at the top of each file test script

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
```

### Eslint extension

- `yarn add -D eslint-plugin-cypress` (https://github.com/cypress-io/eslint-plugin-cypress)
- Add these lines to `.eslintrc`

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:cypress/recommended"
  ]
}
```

### Specify cy in eslintrc globals

```
{
  "globals": {
    "cy": true
  }
}
```

Add this to `.eslintrc`

> cy is a global variable. Much like location. So really it is window.cy. You can add it to the globals in Eslint. Don't import cy from cypress.

Reference: [ESLint: 'cy' is not defined (Cypress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58982852/eslint-cy-is-not-defined-cypress)

Comment: Thank youy. I did try solutions I found online but I must have done something wrong. Your solutions fixed my problem.