# Command cy stays undefined while using the eslint cypress plugin and extending it in the configs

Tags: typescript, cypress, eslint, cypress-component-test-runner

I want to do Component Testing with Cypress, for that I have follolwed the docs and used the automatic file creation for Component Testing. For that I clicked on "Component Testing" in this overview:

[image]

It created the file `component-index.html` and `components.ts`. In `components.ts` I only added `util/i18n` and `tailwind`, everything else is how it came.

Then I wrote a simple test for a Button, which was inside `src/components`:

```
// src/components/Button.cy.tsx
import Button from './Button';

describe('<Button />', () => {
    it('renders', () => {
        cy.mount(<Button label="foo" onClick={() => {}} />);
        cy.get('button').should('have.text', 'foo');
    });
});
```

But `cy` cannot be found.

> Cannot find name 'cy'. ts(2304)

I have an eslint error, but when runnding the test, it asserts correctly.

I have checked those two previous StackOverflow Questions that had a similar issue, and followed the answer:

- [ESLint: 'cy' is not defined (Cypress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58982852/eslint-cy-is-not-defined-cypress)
- [Cypress and cy undefined in commands.js, but everything works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68337033/cypress-and-cy-undefined-in-commands-js-but-everything-works)

What I have done is to install the following package: https://github.com/cypress-io/eslint-plugin-cypress and follow the README described. In short I added the following things into my `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": ["plugin:cypress/recommended"],
  "plugins": ["cypress"],
}
```

I also tried adding the following to the config, but with no change in behaviour:

```json
{
  "globals": {
    "cy": true
  }
}
```

What *did* work, but which I would prefer not to use, was to add the following to the top of the testing file:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
```

I want to avoid doing this, because it would mean more manual labour. Eslint config should take care of it, in my opinion. This also added a new issue of `.mount()` not being recognised:

> Property 'mount' does not exist on type 'cy & CyEventEmitter'. ts(2339)

### I expected the eslint config and plugin to fix the issue, which it didn't

My Cypress versions are the following:

```
        "cypress": "12.7.0",
        "cypress-mochawesome-reporter": "3.3.0",
        "cypress-multi-reporters": "1.6.2",
        "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.14.0",
```

Answer (score 2):

If `/// <reference types="cypress" />` is working but you are reluctant to use it in each file, be aware that you can add it *once only* to the top of `/support/e2e/ts`.

That file is effectively made part or each spec that runs, sort of global pre-spec script, which is why custom commands are defined here.

Also note with typescript and lint changes the effect is not the same as hot-module reload, you may need to restart the editor to see effective changes.

Comment: I wasn't awary of this option, thank you. But then I would keep having the other issue of `mount()` not being typed. I was able to find another solution to my problem, I will answer my own question with it.

Comment: Yes you're right, I did not see you were using `cy.mount()`  in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was as follows. One mistake I made in my initial question was referring to it as an ESLint issue, which prevented me from considering the `tsconfig` at all. The explanation below outlines how I resolved the issue:

Inside my `tsconfig.json` file that is in the root of the project, I added the following into my configs:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["cypress"],
  }
}
```

And then inside my `global.d.ts` file, I added what was already defined inside `cypress/support/components.ts`:

```
import { mount } from 'cypress/react';

declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            mount: typeof mount;
        }
    }
}
```

This way it made it possible for me to test components outside the `cypress` folder and next to my components.